# CollectionFS : Show images after upload

Tags: meteor

This maybe a noob question but how to display the uploaded image after the upload was successful?

Like `<img src='theuploadedimage' />`

Answer (score 4):

Please find the documentation [here](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS#cfsfileurl).

> **cfsFileUrl**: Returns the file URL for the given file, as assigned by
>   the given filehandler.

```
{{#each images}}<!-- images come from Images.find() -->
    <li><p>{{_id}}</p>
        <img src="{{cfsFileUrl fileHandler}}" alt="{{_id}}">
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

The filehandler needs to be defined server-side, e.g.:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var handler = {
        "fileHandler": function (options) {
            return {
                blob: options.blob,
                fileRecord: options.fileRecord
            };
        }
    }
    Images.fileHandlers(handler);
}
```

Where `Images` is your CollectionFS.

You can define many filehandlers for doing different tasks, see for example [here](https://github.com/mxab/cfs-multi-filehandler-example). My example was adapted from [here](https://github.com/mxab/cfsfileurl-example).